I connected a transformer that provides 110V to convert from 230V which has two electrical appliances, and it burned out, what happened?
I have a transformer for two electrical appliances, one electric kettle, and one coffee grinder, I usually disconnect the cable from the transformer to avoid wasting additional electricity and whenever I want to make coffee I reconnect the cable from the transformer into the wall. I live in Santa Cruz, Bolivia and I believe the voltage supply from walls is 230V. This transformer is providing the two electrical appliances 110V. I have these two electrical appliances connected individually to a small three-input rack which is connected to the transformer. It has worked perfectly for multiple months up until today, when I heard a small pop as I connected the transformer to the wall. I then tried to start my kettle and it didn't work. Fearing that I burned out my kettle, I tested another transformer and it seemed to work, but then this transformer stopped working. This other transformer is a forza power technologies transformer with four and four inputs. One side provides 110VAC AVR plus surge protection and the other side provides 220VAC AVR with surge protection. There are three lights, one that says "boost," another that says "power|overheat," and another that says "Buck." The three lights are red, as opposed to green, and it seems to smell a little bit. I have no idea what's happened as this setup worked for me for MONTHS, ever since August. I'd really like to know what's happened in order to avoid burning out new transformers.
Edit: I'm lucky my forza transformer has surge protection. I waited for it to cool off and now its lights are back to green. I am not willing to retry my previous attempt with this transformer, seeing as I've already been given a very nice burnt transformer as my christmas gift.

please add a picture of the transformer

A 110V electric kettle (US plug) likely draws ~ 1 kW, e.g. 10 A. If your transformer can't handle this, it will fail. At moderate overloads it may just overheat slowly, but at heavy overload, it may saturate and fail quite quickly. The coffee grinder is probably only ~ 100 W and is possibly OK. Can't answer without knowing more about the transformer.

Transformer inrush current vs the fuse.
When a transformer is first turned on, it draws a large amount of current, which can be up to 10 times higher than normal. This is called inrush current, and it can cause circuit breakers or fuses to trip. Inrush current is normal and only lasts a few milliseconds.
It's a type of core saturation caused by differences in the way the core was left magnetised when powered off to how it should have been magnetised when re-powered.

it seems to smell a little bit.

Look for a fuse, but it's possible that some other part is broken. perhaps one of the AVR relays is damaged. If you're lucky they're socketed.

to avoid burning out new transformers.

The easiest way to avoid this is don't turn the power off to the transformer.

This transformer is providing the two electrical appliances 110V.

Nobody uses 110, Japan is 100V and USA has been 120V for decades.

It seems Jamaica is using 110V AC, as indicated by this map https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#/media/File:World_Map_of_Mains_Voltages_and_Frequencies,_Detailed.svg

"Nobody uses 110" WRONG... see https://www.screwfix.com/p/carroll-meynell-3000va-intermittent-step-down-isolation-transformer-230v-110v-yellow/17027
